# Counting Inversions with merge sort, Swift

Tags: swift, sorting, merge, counting

I have problem counting inversion with Swift. It takes me 45 minutes and after 45 minutes Xcode crashes. I never get the answer. Can you help me please to figure out what the problem is? Because this problem took people only few seconds. What is wrong with the codes? Btw problem is counting inversions in array(100000 unsorted integers)

```
import UIKit
var count: Int = Int()


func mergeSort(_ array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    guard array.count > 1 else { return array }    

    let middleIndex = array.count / 2              

    let leftArray = mergeSort(Array(array[0..<middleIndex]))


    let rightArray = mergeSort(Array(array[middleIndex..<array.count]))


    return merge(leftPile: leftArray, rightPile: rightArray)             
}
func merge(leftPile: [Int], rightPile: [Int]) -> [Int] {

    var leftIndex = 0
    var rightIndex = 0



    var orderedPile = [Int]()


    while leftIndex < leftPile.count && rightIndex < rightPile.count {
        if leftPile[leftIndex] < rightPile[rightIndex] {
            orderedPile.append(leftPile[leftIndex])
            leftIndex += 1
        } else if leftPile[leftIndex] > rightPile[rightIndex] {
            orderedPile.append(rightPile[rightIndex])
            count += leftPile.count - leftIndex
            rightIndex += 1

        } else {
            orderedPile.append(leftPile[leftIndex])
            leftIndex += 1
            orderedPile.append(rightPile[rightIndex])
            rightIndex += 1
        }
    }


    while leftIndex < leftPile.count {
        orderedPile.append(leftPile[leftIndex])
        leftIndex += 1
    }

    while rightIndex < rightPile.count {
        orderedPile.append(rightPile[rightIndex])
        rightIndex += 1
    }




    return orderedPile

}

func ready(fileName: String) -> [Int] {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "txt") else {
        return [Int]()
    }

    do {
        let numbers = try String(contentsOfFile: path).components(separatedBy: "\r\n")
            .flatMap {Int($0)}
        mergeSort(numbers)




        return numbers
    } catch {
        return [Int]()
    }
}
ready(fileName: "IntegerArray"))
print(count)
```

Comment: Where does it crash and what is the stack backtrace? Does your code work correctly with small arrays? Did you try to *debug* the problem?

Comment: I have tried many times with the small arrays. It works perfectly. It crashes when the ordered pile counts reach to 24999 times and it took me 45 min to reach that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Solved. Do not use playground to run this. Open a x-code project 
and it takes ~1 second.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is here by trying to find Count Inversion Swift 4 version based on Merge Sort

```
import Foundation

func sortAndCount(_ array : [Int]) -> ([Int], Int) {
    guard array.count > 1 else {
        return (array, 0)
    }

    let middleIndex = array.count / 2
    let (leftArray, leftCount)  = sortAndCount(Array(array[0..<middleIndex]))
    let (rightArray, rightCount) = sortAndCount(Array(array[middleIndex..<array.count]))
    let (finalArray, splitCount) = mergeAndCountSplitInversation(leftArray, rightArray)
    return (finalArray, leftCount + rightCount + splitCount)
}

func mergeAndCountSplitInversation(_ leftPile: [Int], _ rightPile: [Int]) -> ([Int], Int) {
    var leftIndex = 0
    var rightIndex = 0
    var orderedPile = [Int]()
    var inversationCount = 0

    while leftIndex < leftPile.count && rightIndex < rightPile.count {
        if leftPile[leftIndex] <= rightPile[rightIndex] {
            orderedPile.append(leftPile[leftIndex])
            leftIndex += 1
        } else {
            orderedPile.append(rightPile[rightIndex])
            rightIndex += 1
            inversationCount = inversationCount + leftPile.count - leftIndex
        }
    }

    while leftIndex < leftPile.count {
        orderedPile.append(leftPile[leftIndex])
        leftIndex += 1
    }

    while rightIndex < rightPile.count {
        orderedPile.append(rightPile[rightIndex])
        rightIndex += 1
    }

    print("inversion for array - \(orderedPile)")
    print("count - \(inversationCount)")
    return (orderedPile, inversationCount)
}

func inverstionCountNaive (_ array :[Int]) -> Int {
    var inverstionCount = 0
    for i in 0..<array.count-1 {
        for j in i+1..<array.count {
            if array[i] > array[j] {
              inverstionCount += 1
            }
        }
    }

    return inverstionCount
}

let array = [2, 1, 3, 1, 2]

print("origin - \(array)")
print("sorted - \(sortAndCount(array))")
print("naive approuch count - \(inverstionCountNaive(array))")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some things about your implementation that are holding things up. I rebuilt your project in a playground, and compared your code to the following, which I think is a more "classical" way to implement the algorithm:

```
func mergeAlt(leftPile: [Int], rightPile: [Int]) -> [Int] {

    var leftPileCopy = leftPile
    var rightPileCopy = rightPile

    var orderedPile = [Int]()

    while !leftPileCopy.isEmpty && !rightPileCopy.isEmpty {
        if leftPileCopy.first! <= rightPileCopy.first! {
            orderedPile.append(leftPileCopy.first!)
            leftPileCopy.removeFirst()
        } else {
            orderedPile.append(rightPileCopy.first!)
            rightPileCopy.removeFirst()
        }
    }

    // By this stage, only one array will have anything in it
    while !leftPileCopy.isEmpty {
        orderedPile.append(leftPileCopy.first!)
        leftPileCopy.removeFirst()
    }

    while !rightPileCopy.isEmpty {
        orderedPile.append(rightPileCopy.first!)
        rightPileCopy.removeFirst()
    }
    return orderedPile
}
```

You'll notice the key difference here is that this implementation compares the first item from each array and then removes whichever one is smaller, progressively reducing the size of the arrays. I think your method, which tracks the position in each array using indices, is what is causing the hold-up.

For instance, I ran this on the playground against your implementation on an array of 1000 random numbers. Your algorithm runs the "compare" section of code (i.e. "if leftPile[index] < rightPile[index]...") almost 8000 times for each pile, and then runs the code to handle the residual code (i.e. the section starting "while leftIndex < leftPile.count...") over 1000 times for each pile. The above implementation runs 500 times for the comparison test and then 4 times to handle any residual elements.

Could you run this for your larger array and let me know if it helps?

Comment: I stop the program after I waited 1 hour 30 minutes with your codes. There should be something wrong.